# How to perform a many-to-many or (at least) a outer-join in SPSS

Tags: many-to-many, spss, outer-join

usually I use [R] for my data analysis, but these days I have to use SPSS. I was expecting that data manipulation might get a little bit more difficult this way, but after my first day I kind of surrender :D and I really would appreciate some help ...
My problem is the following:

- I have two data sets, which have an ID number. Neither data sets have a unique ID (in one data set, which should have unique IDs, there is kind of a duplicated row)
- In a perfect world I would like to keep this duplicated row and simply perform a many-to-many-join. But I accepted, that I might have to delete this "bad" row (in dataset A) and perform a 1:many-join (join dataset B to dataset A, which contains the unique IDs).
- If I run the join (and accept that it seems not to be possible to run a 1:many, but only a many:1-join), I have the problem, that I lose IDs. If I join dataset A to dataset B I lose all cases, that are not part of dataset B. But I really would like to have both IDs like in a full join or something.

Do you know if there is (kind of) a simple solution to my problem?

Example:

dataset A:

| ID | VAL1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | D |
| 3 | K |
| 4 | A |

dataset B:

| ID | VAL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | g |
| 2 | k |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | c |
| 5 | d |
| 5 | a |
| 2 | x |

expected result (best solution):

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | g |
| 1 | B | g |
| 2 | D | k |
| 3 | K | NA |
| 4 | A | a |
| 2 | D | x |

expected result (second best solution):

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | g |
| 2 | D | k |
| 3 | K | NA |
| 4 | A | a |
| 5 | NA | c |
| 5 | NA | d |
| 5 | NA | a |
| 2 | D | x |

what I get (worst solution):

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | g |
| 2 | D | k |
| 4 | A | a |
| 5 | NA | c |
| 5 | NA | d |
| 5 | NA | a |
| 2 | D | x |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example It looks like what you need is a full many to many join, based on the ID's existing in dataset A. You can get this by creating a full Cartesian-Product of the two dataset, using dataset A as the first\left dataset.
The following syntax assumes you have the STATS CARTPROD extention command installed. If you don't you can see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/programmability_option/python_uber_installed_extensions.html) about installing it.

First I'll recreate your example to demonstrate on:

```
dataset close all.
data list list/id1  vl1  (2F3) .
begin data 
1   232
1   433
2   456
3   246
4   468
end data.
dataset name aaa.

data list list/id2  vl2  (2F3) .
begin data 
1   111
2   222
4   333
5   444
5   555
5   666
2   777
3   888
end data.
dataset name bbb.
```

Now the actual work is fairly simple:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE aaa.
STATS CARTPROD VAR1=id1 vl1 INPUT2=bbb VAR2=id2 vl2
/SAVE OUTFILE="C:\somepath\yourcartesianproduct.sav".

* The new dataset now contains all possible combinations of rows in the two datasets.
* we will select only the relevant combinations, where the two ID's match.
select if id1=id2.
exe.
```